# Find char element in array of char in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with finding specific char element in array of characters.
I know how to make it with intigers,but I have no idea how to do it with char elements.
There is my code with working integer search.
Thanks

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    st = br.readLine();
    searchKey = Integer.parseInt(st);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("input-output error");
    return;
}
for (i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (B[i] == searchKey) {
        found = true;
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(searchKey + " Value is found pozicija " + (i + 1));
        c++;
    }
    if (c == 0 && i == B.length - 1) {
        System.out.println("Value  " + searchKey + " not found...!");
    }
}
c = 0;
break;
```

Updated:

```
        char A[][] = new char [10][10]; // Matricas inicializaacija
        char B[] = new char [55];   // Vektora inicializaacija
        char C[] = new char [10];   // Vektora inicializaacija
        char D[] = new char [10];   // Vektora inicializaacija
```

I just have array A[][].It is 2D array,whish is fulled with random numbers,there is array B[],how in our university called vectorial array,where all A[i][j] nubmers are shown in one line "Print".
And now,user should input char which he wants to find in B array and with BufferReader help programm should output:Posotion of the char in array,if it is not found output"Value not found".

Comment: Show us the code you've used for chars.

Comment: And please tell us *what* the problem actually is

Comment: Your search key is always an Integer, so it can't find chars. Just adapt that one line.

Comment: Actually just do `searchKey = br.readLine();` and omit the following line. And use `.equals()` instead of `==` when you are matching Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

 public static final String EXIT_COMMAND = "exit";

 public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("Enter some text, or '" + EXIT_COMMAND + "' to quit");

  while (true) {

   System.out.print("> ");
   String input = br.readLine();

   // Creating array of string length 
   char[] ch = new char[input.length()];

   // Copy character by character into array 
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    ch[i] = input.charAt(i);
   }
   //looking for the "h" char
   for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if ('h' == ch[i]) {
     System.out.println("*** Found....");
    } else {
     System.out.println("Not Found....");
    }
   }


   if (input.length() == EXIT_COMMAND.length() && input.toLowerCase().equals(EXIT_COMMAND)) {
    System.out.println("Exiting.");
    return;
   }

  }
 }
}
```